# se puede cambiar el url de un link?

Tags: javascript

lo que pasa es que tengo un link ya creado desde un inicio

```html
<a href="/urlParaCambiar"> link
```

y luego marco un checkbox de varios checkboxes y quiero modificar el url del link, agregando el valor del checkbox al url del link para mandarlo desde GET

asi:

```
<a href="/urlParaCambiar+"elvalorDelCheckMarcado""> link
```

Comment: Hubman , Qué formato tiene la `urlparaCambiar` es un `archivo.php`?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes realizar eso utilizando Jquery

```
    $("#id").attr("href", "https://www.example.com/jquery");
```

Usando Jquery y seleccionando el id de tu "< a >" con $("") y colocando attr("href","nuevaurl") puedes cambiar la url segun te parezca

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varias opciones para cambiar el valor de un atributo, mas o menos compatibles con los diversos navegadores, **sin** necesidad de usar nada mas que Javascript *puro* y *duro*.

Una vez localizado el elemento en si (mediante `GetElementById( )` o de cualquier otra forma), puedes usar:

- `X.attributes["href"] = "NUEVA_HREF"`.
- `X.href = "NUEVA_HREF"`.
- `X.setAttribute( "href", "NUEVA_HREF" )`.

Una amplia lista de métodos de acceso la tienes disponible en

[DOM methods and properties that are for all implementations](https://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#attributes)

junto al soporte en varios navegadores. No está muy actualizada, pero te puede valer para orientarte.